# Python3 Dictionary BLANK after first operation

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I am reading a CSV file into Dictreader and want to print its contents twice on the terminal. But it is printing only once. Is Dictreader BLANK after first print?

```
dictreader = csv.DictReader(reader)

for k in dictreader:
    print(k)         # Prints all keys/values

for i in dictreader:
    print(i)         # Doesn't print anything
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if you look at the [source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/csv.py#L81) for `DictReader` you'll see it's an iterator (has an implementation for `__next__` and `__iter__` returns `self`).

After going through it once it will be exhausted; consequent iterations will simply not produce anything. You could create a list from it if you need to iterate through it more times.

Answer (score 0):

All `csv` wrappers wrap file-like objects. File-like objects have state, specifically, the seek position (and pipes can't seek at all), so the wrappers allow the object to manage position, parsing whatever comes next.

Making iteration work twice in a row would mean the `csv` wrappers have to cache the file contents (consuming unbounded amounts of memory) or require them to seek back to the beginning of the underlying file (not possible for streaming file-like objects).

Think of the `csv` wrappers as semi-file-like makes this easier to grasp. You can't do `for line in myfile:` twice in a row without seeking, and similarly, you can't do `for row in mycsv:` twice in a row without seeking the underlying file-like object.

Assuming your reader is seekable, you could iterate it twice (without consuming unbounded memory) by doing:

```
dictreader = csv.DictReader(reader)

for k in dictreader:
    print(k)         # Prints all keys/values

reader.seek(0)  # Restart from beginning

for i in dictreader:
    print(i)         # Prints all keys/values
```

Or if the files are known to be small, you could cache:

```
# Cache reusable values
dictlines = tuple(csv.DictReader(reader))

for k in dictlines:
    print(k)         # Prints all keys/values

for i in dictlines:
    print(i)         # Prints all keys/values
```

You could also use `itertools.tee` for the same purpose, but that only helps if all iterators are going to be advanced (somewhat) in tandem; if you're running one to completion before starting the next, it's usually faster to just cache to `list` or `tuple`.